# deserialize json array to a certain type

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON string -

```
"[
{\"id\":0,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 001.jpg\"},
{\"id\":1,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 002.jpg\"},
{\"id\":2,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 003.jpg\"},
{\"id\":3,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 004.jpg\"},
{\"id\":4,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 005.jpg\"},
{\"id\":5,\"picurl\":\"/pics/kuku/Picture 006.jpg\"},
{\"id\":6,\"picurl\":\"\"}
]"
```

recieved from client.

How can I parse it to a  List of picITEM ???

```
public  class picITEM
{
    string id {get;set;}
    string picurl { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 IList<picITEM> persons = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<picITEM>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json.Net nugget package. Include that package in your project and write below code:

```
List<picITEM> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(yourvaribaleofjson);
```

I took the list as your question state that you are getting multiple json values.

[JSON.NET nugget url](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Please let me know if you face any trouble.